# Visual Studio for mac project.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

When I use Visual Studio for Mac to create a web project with .Net core 1.1, there is no project.json in my project. Is there any mistake when I create
[this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLQ79.png)?

Comment: [link](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj)ok, looks like they changed project.json into .csproj, but there is an new  problem ,when i use <dotnet ef migrations add Init> command to init my database under my project dic, then it throw <No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef">

Comment: You need to add a tool reference for the EF command line tools in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project.json was never released in production. It was replaced by a new, [vastly simplified MSBuild project format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects) before .NET Core was released. The new format works a lot like the `project.json` format - it supports globbing, package references and compiles all `*.cs* files found in a folder. You don't need to define dependent packages in the project file any more, you can specify *one* root package and all dependencies will be added when you execute`dotnet restore`

.NET Core allows you to add commandlets that appear as commands to the .NET CLI. `dotnet watch` executes the `dotnet-watch` executable. `dotnet ef` searches for and executes the `dotnet-ef` executable.

You have to add an option to the MSBuild project that installs the tool in the first place with the `<DotNetCliToolReference>` element. After that, `dotnet restore` will install the tool just like any other package.

This is described in [.NET Core Command Line Tools for EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet).

The MSBuild project file should look like this :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This file is *enough* to build your project and execute `ef` commands from the command line, since all `*.cs` files will be compiled by default

Comment: Thanks, dotnet-ef command was running successful after i edit .csporj file add DotNetCliToolReference node ,also i changed version for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet, now it works good

Answer (score 1):

`project.json` is deprecated and was never supported outside preview .NET Core tooling in VS 2015. The new tooling uses `csproj` files and can be used in VS 2017 and VS for Mac (and others like VSCode, Rider, …).